# Sequence inequality proof using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, recursion

I have an increasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $0 < x_1 < 1$ and a recursive estimate
$$x_n^2 \leq x_1^2 + x_{n-1}^4(1-x_1^2)$$
I want to prove
$$\sup_n x_n^2 \leq \frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1^2}$$

---

Trying induction:

For $n = 1$, since we have for the denominator $0 <1-x_1^2 <1$, the inequality holds.

Assume the inequality holds for $n=k$, giving us
$$\sup_k x_k^2 \leq \frac{x_k^2}{1-x_k^2}$$

Now if I consider
$$x_{k+1}^2\leq x_1^2 + x^4_{k}(1-x_1^2)$$
Now since I have a order 4 term, it makes it difficult to get back the previous form. Since the RHS of the inequality looks like the sum of a geometric series
$$S_n = x_1^2 +x_1^4 +x_1^6+...$$
I think there should be a way to write the order 4 term as a larger sum that I can have as a power of this GP but I can't figure it out. Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove by induction.

For $n = 1$, since we have for the denominator $0 <1-x_1^2 <1$, the inequality holds.

Assume the inequality holds for $n=k$, giving us
$$\sup_{1\le i \le k} x_i^2 \leq  \color{red}{\frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1^2}}$$

For $n = k+1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x_{k+1}^2 \le x_1^2 + x_k^4 (1-x_1^2) &\le  x_1^2 + \left( \frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1^2} \right)^2 (1-x_1^2) \\
&= x_1^2 + \frac{x_1^4}{1-x_1^2} \\
&= x_1^2 \left(1 + \frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1^2}  \right) \\
&= \frac{x_1^2}{1-x_1^2} \\
\end{align}
$$
So, the statement holds true for $n = k+1$.

Q.E.D

Comment: Thanks for the help, you even found the mistake I made in the post. How could I have not noticed those terms cancelled out!

Comment: @MichaelB You're welcome!